# How to query the next set of records from an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest

I am querying salesforce database to get some data. The query result will return a max of 2000 records in one response and will also return the "nextRecordsUrl" parameter, using which we can fetch the next set of results. So I am able to achieve this by calling the same method again in the done function of the $.ajax(). I wanted to know if there was any better way to do it?

```
function stringSearch(queryParam){
    var sessionCookie = getCookie('sid');
    var currentDomain = window.location.host;

        queryParam = queryParam== undefined || queryParam =='' ? "/services/data/v28.0/query/?q=SELECT+Name+from+Account" : queryParam;
        $.ajax({
            url : "https://"+currentDomain+queryParam,
            headers : {"Authorization": "Bearer "+ sessionCookie},
            contentType : "application/json"
        }).done(function(res){
            //do some processing with the result
                    processingFunction(res.records);
            if(res.nextRecordsUrl){
                //call the same method with different parameters
                stringSearch(res.nextRecordsUrl);
            }else{
                //Done with all the processing proceed to final actions 
            }
        }).fail(function(err){
            alert('Oops!! We were unable to fetch the data you requested!\n'+JSON.stringify(err)+'\n ');
        });
 }

 function processingFunction(){
    //use the array and do some processing. 

 }
```

Comment: Your solution seems pretty good to me. Maybe the only thing I would change is to retry the ajax request a limited number of times if some error occurs.

Comment: Looks solid, imo. Well handled recursion.

Comment: Depending on how much processing you are going to do on the data, you may want to query the new data before you do the processing so they both occur async.

Comment: @megawac: I have edited my question. I am calling the `processingFunction` from the done method. I assume the code will wait for the `processingFunction` to finish the processing on the data passed and then the `stringSearch` will be called from the done method. Is there a way to it async way?

Comment: If you move the `stringSearch` recursive line above the `processingFunction` the client will go request the next set of data before trying to process the data. Depending on how long `processingFunction` takes to process the set of data this may be useful. Note: This will also complicate your code and I suggest you look into using `promises` if you decided to use this approach (as if the processing function takes longer than the next request to complete and be processed order will not be maintained).